# C# Connecting Web Page with Winform No ws

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

Is there any way to connect my web application (in a server) with a winform (or console) application that is in another computer in the same network?

Will it be enough with knowing the IP?

THanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just make a request from the winForm app to the web site using the WebClient class

More info here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33798/HTTP-GET-with-NET-WebClient

Comment: But How I call this WebClient from my web page?
As far as I understand, this make that my winform is waiting for something... But How I send it that thing?